# How can I know by inspection that a process is WSS?

Tags: stochastic-processes

I have some codes to generate three different Random Sequences:

I am getting a 4x100 matrixes where 4 is the number of samples and 100 is the length of the process. I am getting these results:
[image]
[image]

[image]

I know that in order a WSS if the mean is constant and if its autocorrelation only depends on $\tau=t_{1}-t_{2}$ But, by inspection and even to calculate these values, I am kind of confused since I am working with a set of data instead a mathematical model. I would like to know if after calculating the mean of each sample (each row for each matrix) of the random processes as well as the autocorrelation, if they are equal, then I can say that they are WSS and also what information could I get only based on the images?